# Database is not being selected in php doc

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

Hi so i have a database 'guestbook' and created it using phpmyadmin however i am struggling with selecting this database within my php doc.

```
<?php
$link=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password');
if(!$link){
    die('Not connected: ');
}
$db_selected=mysqli_select_db($link, 'guestbook');
if(!$db_selected) {
    die("Can't use guestbook : ");
}
?>
```

It seems to connect properly however it returns "Can't use guestbook : ". Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Change `mysql_error()` to `mysqli_error()` you can't mix your APIs

Comment: I just took them out, didn't change anything

Answer (score 1):

You only specified the host in `mysqli_connect`.

```
$link = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
```

Comment: I filled the parameters but still returns "can't use guestbook"

Answer (score 0):

Can you let me know is 'guestbook' a database or a table. If it is table then it will give you the error. As mysqli_select_db expects a database name not the table name.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your connection before set database by adding after `$link=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password');`
 :

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
```